# Not able to click on facebook app permission page

Tags: selenium-webdriver, watir, selenium-ruby

[image]
I am automating facebook signup process with app permission. After facebook login, app permission page is showing on facebook. I want to click on Continue button but not able to click on this button. I am using watir/selenium ruby.

```
facebook_email.set ("abc@punchh.com")
facebook_pass.set ("test1234")      
facebook_submit.click
@browser.button(:xpath => "//button[@type, 'submit' and text()='Continue as Rohit']").click
```

Comment: "I want to click on Continue button but not able to click on this button."  Is there an error?  Does it silently fail?  Have you inspected the element to make sure it's actually a button?

Comment: I have seen this window many a times but I am trying to get that window as possible as I can but I couldn't locate it. If you guide me how to reach this window, I can help you, the above seems to be Javascript window, may be write this code `b.alert.ok`, If it doesn't work, please guide me through anything to reach that page.

Comment: Can you show us the html structure of this page?

Comment: I got solution solution for this. This is my updated code:                   def facebook_signup
  facebook_link.click
  @browser.window(:title,/Log in to Facebook | Facebook/i).use do
   facebook_email.set ("abc@punchh.com")
   facebook_pass.set ("test1234")
   facebook_submit.click
   if (@browser.window(:index => 1).exists?)
    @browser.window(:index => 1).use do
     @browser.button(:name => "__CONFIRM__").click
    end
   end
   sleep 10
  end
 end

Comment: Update as answer , write as answer .

Comment: I have used index based browser which follows zero based index ordering. Index of default window is "0". As we click on submit button then new window opens whose index is "1". So i have checked that if window with index: 1 present then switch to window with index:1 by using command (@browser.window(:index => 1).use) and execute operation. This works for me.

Comment: I think you are new to Stack over flow, when you are writing to me, mark my name with @Rajagopalan so that I will be notified. I understood your answer when you were telling me first time, but I am asking you to write as an answer so that people those who are coming to this question will an answer, you can write have an answer to your own question.

Comment: @Rajagopalan thanks for your suggestion...

Comment: Not sure if you're using a headless browser, but if you're not, and you use a mac, `cliclick` might be able to help